# Best place to put a "saveAll" method/function

Tags: python, django, oop

I have a Model class that is structured as follows:

```
class Item(models.Model):

    place = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    item_id = models.IntegerField()
    # etc.

    @classmethod
    def from_obj(cls, **kwargs):
        i = Item()
        # populate this from json data
        # which needs a lot of translations applied
        # before saving the data
```

So, from the above I have a way to create an `Item` instance via the `from_obj` classmethod. Now I want to process a json array that contains about 100 objects to create those 100 Item instances. Where should this be put? The function/method would look something like this:

```
def save_all():
    objects = requests.get(...).json()
    for obj in objects:
        item = Item.from_obj(obj)
        item.save()
```

Should this be a `staticmethod` within `Item`. A plain function outside it? Or should another class be created to 'manage' the Item. What is usually considered the best practice for something like this pattern?

Comment: I'd use one of your first two options. Both will do the job. Having an extra class is not nessesary.

Comment: It looks like you’re using some sort of framework/library, is that relevant to the question?

Comment: Use `cls`, not `Item`, to create the instance. This lets subclasses decide what type of instance to get by calling `Item.from_obj`, `ChildAOfItem.from_obj`, `ChildBOfItem.from_obj`, etc.

Comment: @KlausD. the `models.Model` class in inherited from django's ORM, but that's about the extent of using Django (saving to the DB). But other than field integrity and the save/delete method, I don't think it's too relevant.

Comment: After giving it some thought, we might need more information in order to find the best solution for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was pure Python, I'd say either use a plain function or make it a classmethod.

Now this is django's ORM, and [the convention for "table-level" operations here is to put them in a custom `ModelManager` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods).

**EDIT** Except that in your example, there's an outgoing HTTP request, which suggests it might be better as a plain function - it's closer to a view or management command than to a ModelManager method

> Why does python encourage one way and django encourages another way?

Python itself doesn't "encourage" anything special, those (plain function or classmethod) are just the obvious choices - it doesn't make sense to make this an instancemethod (you don't need any instance here) nor a staticmethod (since you do use the class).

Django's ORM is, well, an ORM - a framework that tries to provide a Python representation of the (rather formal and specialized) domain  of relational databases. Separating row-level operations (model classes methods) from table-level operations (modelmanager classes) makes sense in this context.

Comment: I see. Why does python encourage one way and django encourages another way?

Answer (score 1):

The [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method is ideal for this, you can add an additional classmethod that calls the API and bulk creates all the objects

```
@classmethod
def bulk_create_from_api(cls):
    objects = requests.get(...).json()
    cls.objects.bulk_create([cls.from_obj(obj) for obj in objects])
```

Used like this

```
Item.bulk_create_from_api()
```

**Please note:** bulk_create does not send any signals like pre_save or post_save

Comment: to clarify, are you saying that this `save_all()` should be from within a classmethod inside `Item`? If so, why a `classmethod` and not for instance a `staticmethod` or `ItemManager` class or something else?

Comment: Because a classmethod has a reference to the cls that it was called for and any subclasses of your class would also inherit this method. This could be a "mixin" that you could add to many classes when used as a classmethod. A manager method would also work since the manager should have access to the original model

Comment: `bulk_create` dont have signals.

Comment: @cetver that's true, that condition wasn't specified however. I'll add a not to the answer

Comment: @IainShelvington judging by the code comments TS uses some I18n behavior that affected signals

Comment: @IainShelvington why a classmethod and not a staticmethod though?

Comment: @cetver I don't see any mention of signals in the OP?

Comment: @David542 staticmethods do not receive the class they were called on, it makes the class less extendable as you would have to hardcode the Item class in the method. The method is also related to the class since it creates instances of it, so it makes sense from a logical point of view

Comment: A staticmethod generally does not do anything with the class it is defined on. It is usually just a utility function that is loosely related to the class and is a nicety that prevents you from having to import a load of functions along with the class when you are using it